# Capistrano Rails deploy - authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app onto a Digital Ocean Ruby on Rails droplet. I thought it would be all set up to go and I'd just have to configure the app. But it's actually just like a standard Linux server.

I'm using [this guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04) to set up the droplet, but had to tweak a few things to get them running. When I run `cap production deploy`, I get the following error message:

```
#<Thread:0x0000555b2f0ec948@/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    11: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    10: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
     9: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/capistrano-passenger-0.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/passenger.cap:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     8: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in `test'
     7: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     6: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     5: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     4: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
     3: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
     2: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
     1: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:268:in `start': Authentication failed for user michael@178.128.223.202 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
    1: from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as michael@178.128.223.202: Authentication failed for user michael@178.128.223.202 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as michael@178.128.223.202: Authentication failed for user michael@178.128.223.202


Caused by:
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user michael@178.128.223.202

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my `deploy.rb` file:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.14.1"

set :application, "MyApp"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:MyAccount/MyApp.git"

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/michael/my-app/#{fetch :application}"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system", "public/uploads", "vendor/bundle", ".bundle"

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5
```

And the deploy/production.rb file:

```
server "123.456.789.123", user: "me", roles: %w{app db web}

  set :ssh_options, {
    config: false,
    keys: %w[/home/myhome/.ssh/id_ed25519],
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w[publickey],
    user: 'me'
  }
```

Any help here would be good. All the other answers I've seen so far haven't fixed the problem for me (and none have had `Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger`)

Comment: I have been using Capistrano for most of my rails application. Refer to this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma). Even though the document points to the ubuntu 14, it will work very well for ubuntu 18+ versions.

Comment: I followed the intstructions in the link you sent, and I keep getting 1 of 2 errors. Without `sudo` it says that the connection was closed by the remote host (though the IP is the same as the server the app is being run on) caused by EOFError. With `sudo` it says there is an error with the Capfile: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- airbrussh/capistrano`. Not sure where to go from here

Comment: whats the capistrano version!!

Comment: check this method I always get success https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04

Also problem is with SSHkit gem now it uses ed25519 and bcrypt_pbkdf encryption. Both are gems should be in development of gemfile